# Displaying bullet formatting in html using c#

Tags: c#, html, list

An example that I have that could direct me into the right direction is this:

```
String Text = Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

I understand what this is going to do. But the issue is this: I have a  memo box on my website a user types in a bulleted list in this memo box and then it appears as html on my webpage.

Example of Bulleted list:

> • Item 1
>
> - List item 1.1
> - List item 1.2

When it displays in the website as HTML the Bulleted list looks like this:

> • Item1
>
> o List item 1.1
>
> o List item 1.2

It loses its indentation. Code that i have found and tried only gave indentation once

```
String Text = Text .Replace("\t\t", "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;");
```

This does work, but it does not give indentation to the second level of the bulleted list. I have also no idea how to find it when a bullet is on the second level and then just double the spaces if it is like that.

Any insight will be very helpfull as I have hit a wall with this. I am using C# to replace characters with html

Comment: Change the css styling. This has nothing to do with c#.

Comment: How can I do that? This is in a memo box, someone types it in the memo box and then it appears on the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After alot of research i found a way that sort of fit my needs.

What i had to do was use this [plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/) instead. That way the user can add bulleted list and the indentation would be the same on the webpage. I however ran into another problem while using this plugin where i got the error "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client". I found an answer  [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1223756.aspx?%20Net%20equivalent%20of%20php%20s%20html%20purifier) that solved my problem for that too. It is now working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace the breaks with `<li></li>` tags if you are planning to render a list on a website.

A list of items on a website usually follows the following syntax:

```
<ol>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ol>
```

You can also have sublists e.g:

```
<ol>
    <li>Item 1    
<ol>
    <li>Sub Of Item 1</li>
    <li>Sub Of Item 1</li>
</ol>
</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ol>
```

I would suggest having the memobox on the website work as a HTML editor rather than save rich text and then trying to convert that to HTML.